# pyqt4 Button image doesnt appear in .app

Tags: pyqt4, py2app

I create an .app using py2app, and the GUI was made with pyqt4, and one of the buttons has an image on ti, but when i run the app the image doesnt appear and when i run it on the terminal it appears, how can I solve this?

Thank you in advance

Comment: How are you referencing the image? Is it embedded or referenced by path?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

when you launch python setup.py py2app you can pass two extra arguments:

```
--iconfile path/to/icon.icns 
--resources path/to/other/required/stuff
```

With the first one you set the Dock and App icon, with the second one you embed other needed resources into the .app folder, so that they are available when the app is started.